# Tailwind Line Clamp not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

Tailwind Line clamp plugin is working on certain areas and not on others. for android and windows browsers its working fine but when I test on ios the line clamp doesnt work

Here is an image showing the error

[Line Clamping not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCO8d.png)
Here is the line of code using line clamp

`<p class="text-sm text-gray-300 line-clamp-2" v-html="topArticle.data.description"/>`

am using the same property on another line of code an it works perfectly

[Line Clamp Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLyNm.png)

Below is the working code

`<p class="mt-3 font-medium text-sm text-gray-300 line-clamp-3" v-html="videoArticle.description"/>`